# Django cli print correct traceback

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get Django to print the traceback of the error raised instead of the one of its choosing:

```
class Comand(BaseCommand):
    ...
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            ...
        except:
            e, c, b = sys.exc_info()
            traceback.print_tb(b) # <-- this prints what I want
            raise CommandError, 'message', b # <-- this results in wront traceback
```

In other words, I want that when `manage.py` is called like this:

```
./manage.py command --traceback
```

the traceback printed will be the one from the actual error, and not the Django one.

I couldn't find where Django prints the actual message it prints.

---

OK, found the relevant Django code:

```
def run_from_argv(self, argv):
    ...
    try:
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    except Exception as e:
        if options.traceback or not isinstance(e, CommandError):
            raise
```

why wouldn't this preserve my backtrace?

Comment: Did you try to make `except Exception as e: print(e)` ?

Comment: @sebb Yes, I know what exception I get, that's not the problem. Django reraises the exception and loses the backtrace - that's the problem.

Comment: Did you try `traceback.format_exc()`

Comment: @sebb I'm getting the correct backtrace, the problem is that when Django reraises the exception, it throws away my backtrace and uses its own.